# What is Colin Tate's job in Possessor?

Tags: plot-explanation, possessor

In the sci-horror movie, ***Possessor***, the possessed Colin Tate goes to work, puts on a VR glasses, sits in his virtual office and starts spying on other people's lives; and while spying, he starts to read out styles, material of different curtains he sees.

What exactly is his job?

I am fully aware that this movie is based on a fictional world therefore there will be odd jobs that we do not have in real life; but how Colin Tate does his job completely confuses me.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding he is teaching AI how to identify objects in images/videos.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure its a data collection company that sells information to advertisers and marketing agencies.  Its a virtual sweatshop of sorts.  First to escape the monotony and gloom of sitting in a large dimmed room with dozens of other employees, the virtual glasses are provided to take the employee to his or her "cubicle".  Then the next layer of reality is viewed on a virtual laptop on the virtual desk.  From there employees are exposed to the "private' lives of people through their webcams and smartphone cameras...  not exactly private, but we can assume these subjects have accepted the Permissions to access these portals at some benefit, maybe a free app, a membership, or monetary compensation, etc..

The sweatshop employ then has to identify the things that they see and hear in the videos, items, brands, materials, media, shows on the TV,  etc... then I would assume these huge volumes of data are compiled and SOLD to the above-mentioned agencies for a large profit.  Really not much different than what is happening in real life right now.  I guess this would be the next level of personal data collection, and probably hits the mark on the direction we're going with the desire to know What People Want.

[Side note.  I think Vos starts to become unraveled at the work station because the "job" adds to many layers of false reality to her already massive shift in reality.  Vos herself exists in the real world at a very sterile and spartan facility where she is treated with a mixture of respect and abuse.  She is then shifted/sent to experience the world through another humans faculties, then that person goes to work, puts on VR goggles and goes to the virtual cubicle with large windows looking out on large beautiful scenery, then finally shifts her perceptions through a webcam to look into the lives of random people doing random and sometimes raunchy things.... that's a lot of levels of false reality, and I'm sure her head was spinning.]

Comment: good insight. It is also very interesting to me that Colin Tate is working as a lowly employee in his will-be father-in-law enterprise. The amount contempt, hostility and animosity from his father-in-law is evident.